# Listen when no toggleButton is pressed on a Togglegroup in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have scene with a "homepage" and a toggleGroup above it with 2 buttons on it, when i click one of them a fxml is loadead to the hbox below the toggleGroup. So, what i want to load the home screen when all toggles are unpressed. How can i achieve it?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a listener with the [toggle group's `selectedToggle` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html#selectedToggleProperty):

```
toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((obs, oldToggle, newToggle) -> {
    if (newToggle == null) {
        // load "homepage"
    }
});
```